# How do I get my Atheros AR9485 wireless card to work in Ubuntu Server 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, atheros

So I recently installed Ubuntu Server 16.04 on an old computer to set up as a server. While it was going through the setup process it was connected but when I booted up for the fist time it would not connect. So I looked around for a while and read Ask Ubuntu posts looking for the answer. I found many posts but not any that solved my problem.

I ran `lshw -C network` giving the output:

```
 *-network DISABLED
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: enp3s0
   version: 07
   serial: 40:a8:f0:3c:ef:09
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capacity: 100Mbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
   resources: irq:33 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:d0804000-d0804fff memory:d0800000-d0803fff
*-network
   description: Wireless interface
   product: AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
   logical name: wlp4s0
   version: 01
   serial: b8:ee:65:9e:42:99
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=4.4.0-116-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
   resources: irq:39 memory:fea00000-fea7ffff memory:fea80000-fea8ffff
```

It used to say DISABLED for the AR9485 device but I ran `ifconfig wlp4s0 up` and that fixed that.

I also ran `lsmod | grep ath9k` giving the output:

```
ath9k                 147456  0
ath9k_common           36864  1 ath9k
ath9k_hw              479232  2 ath9k_common,ath9k
ath                    32768  3 ath9k_common,ath9k,ath9k_hw
mac80211              737280  1 ath9k
cfg80211              565248  4 ath,ath9k_common,ath9k,mac80211
```

I also installed rfkill (I had to download it manually and bring it over on a USB stick) and ran `rfkill list all` giving the output:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Next I ran `iwconfig` and got:

```
wlp4s0    IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
    Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm   
    Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
    Power Management:off
```

Then I ran `ifconfig wlp4s0`:

```
lo      Link encap:Local Loopback  
    inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
    inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
    UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
    RX packets:7064 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
    TX packets:7064 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
    collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
    RX bytes:524368 (524.3 KB)  TX bytes:524368 (524.3 KB)

wlp4s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:ee:65:9e:42:99  
    UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
    RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
    TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
    collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
    RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

I don't think it's the driver because I read [this](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/ath9k) page which says the driver which they offer, `ath9k` is part of the kernel and that's the only driver they offer for the Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter.

I also modified /etc/network/interfaces as following:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto wlp4s0
iface wlp4s0 inet dhcp
    wpa-driver wext
    wpa-ssid myessid
    wpa-ap-scan 1
    wpa-proto RSN
    wpa-pairwise CCMP
    wpa-key-mgmt WPA-PSK
    wpa-password mypasshere
```

I am wondering if maybe I should have used `wlan0` instead of `wlp4s0`? But it didn't work either way. I also restarted the network using `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart` but it still didn't work.

Does anybody have any suggestions for me? I'd rather not have to buy another wireless adapter.

Comment: Do you have installed wpa_supplicant package on your system: `dpkg -l | grep supplicant`?

Comment: I checked - yes I do.